# why UIKeyboardTaskQueue lockWhenReadyForMainThread. while using the autofill?

Tags: iphone, flutter, ios16.4

I have a sign in page. I am using the autofill feature to save the username and password. on click of the sign in button I am calling `TextInput.finishAutofillContext(shouldSave: true);`
to save the username and password. It is saving successfully, when I logged out, I pre-fill the username I double click on the username and select username and hit on the password. i have face id enabled on my (IOS 16) device but when I clicked on the password (which on the keyboard suggestion) the application froze

here is my code  (part of code used)

```
AutofillGroup(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.username]),
              TextFormField(autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.password]),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text("Elevated Button", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                onPressed: () {
                  TextInput.finishAutofillContext(shouldSave: true);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Log:

```
KeyboardTaskQueue] -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue lockWhenReadyForMainThread] timeout waiting for task on queue
Keyboard queue task timeout detected
2
 
Last Exception Backtrace:
No stack!
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────<…>
```

I am not able to understand why application freezes there